# Check if value exists in multidimensional List<Of Object> (List of Lists)

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net

I have a List like this:

[image]

How can I check if value exists in this List? 
listaProduktow is a List

```
Private Function PobierzProduktyKategorii(ByVal nazwaSklepu As String, ByVal idSklepKategorie As Integer) As List(Of Object)
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT Id_sklep_kategorie, Id_rodzic FROM SKLEP_KATEGORIE WHERE Usunieto = 0 AND Id_rodzic = @IdSklepKategorie ORDER BY Kolejnosc ASC"
        Dim produkty As List(Of Object) = New List(Of Object)

        Polacz(nazwaSklepu)

        Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
        With sqlCommand
            .Connection = connection
            .CommandText = sql
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdSklepKategorie", idSklepKategorie)
        End With

        Try
            Using dr As MySqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
                If dr.HasRows Then
                    While dr.Read
                        produkty.Add(PobierzProduktyKategorii(nazwaSklepu, dr("Id_sklep_kategorie")))
                    End While
                Else
                    Rozlacz()
                    Polacz(nazwaSklepu)
                    Dim sql2 As String = "SELECT Id_produkty FROM PRODUKTY WHERE Blokada = 0 AND Usunieto = 0 AND Id_sklep_kategorie = @IdSklepKategorie"
                    Dim sqlCommand2 As New MySqlCommand
                    With sqlCommand2
                        .Connection = connection
                        .CommandText = sql2
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdSklepKategorie", idSklepKategorie)
                    End With
                    Using dr2 As MySqlDataReader = sqlCommand2.ExecuteReader()
                        While dr2.Read
                            produkty.Add(dr2("Id_produkty"))
                        End While
                    End Using
                End If
            End Using
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            Logi.LogInfo(ex)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Logi.LogInfo(ex)
        Finally
            Rozlacz()
        End Try


        Return produkty
    End Function
```

Produkty is also a List as you can see at the top of the code. I added values recursivly, by doing this: produkty.add(myFunction()), and this function return an array of Object, thats why is that.

Comment: what type is the array? screenshot isn't much help.

Comment: C# or VB.Net? Please pick one...

Comment: It's a List<Of Object>. I use VB.NET but code in C# would be helpful too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Cast<uint>` and `Enumerable.Contains`:

```
uint[,] array2D = new uint[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
uint value = 6;
bool valueExists = array2D.Cast<uint>().Contains(value); // true
```

---

So you're using VB.NET instead. You also have a `List(Of List(Of Object))` instread of a multidimensional array.

Instead of `Object` you should use `Int32`, so `dr2.GetInt32("Id_produkty")` instead of `dr2("Id_produkty")`. Then you get a `List(Of List(Of Int32))`:

```
Private Function PobierzProduktyKategorii(ByVal nazwaSklepu As String, ByVal idSklepKategorie As Integer) As List(Of List(Of Int32))
    Dim produkty As New List(Of List(Of Int32))
    '  ....  '

     Using dr2 As MySqlDataReader = sqlCommand2.ExecuteReader()
        While dr2.Read
            produkty.Add(dr2.GetInt32("Id_produkty"))
        End While
    End Using
    '  ...  '

    If dr.HasRows Then
        While dr.Read
            produkty.Add(PobierzProduktyKategorii(nazwaSklepu, dr("Id_sklep_kategorie")))
        End While
    Else
        ' ... '
        Dim subList As New List(Of Int32)
        Using dr2 As MySqlDataReader = sqlCommand2.ExecuteReader()
            While dr2.Read
                subList.Add(dr2.GetInt32("Id_produkty"))
            End While
        End Using
        produkty.Add(subList) ' a single list added  '
    End If
    ' ... '
    return produkty
End Function
```

Now you can search these lists with `SelectMany` + `Contains`:

```
Dim allLists As List(Of List(Of Int32)) = PobierzProduktyKategorii("Foo", categoryID)
Dim valueExists As Boolean = allLists.SelectMany(Function(list) list).Contains(value)
```

Comment: But I have List<Of Object> instead of clear array

Comment: @XardasLord: so does `Cast(Of UInteger)().Contains(value)` work? But why do you first mention that you have a multidimensional array and now that it's a `List(Of Object)`? Please provide your code in the first place instead of images. What `Object` is stored in the `List`?

Comment: I get this error: `specified cast is not valid` My bad, I should write that this is List not array

Comment: List contains Objects of another List<Of Object>. It is recursive

Comment: So it's not `List(Of Objct)` but `List(Of MyCustomObjcect)`. You should at least show this class. Can this child class also contain other children or only one level deep?

Comment: It's not `MyCustomObject`, it's just an Object. I added a code, but in my language :/

Comment: @XardasLord With all due respect to you, responses like this are why this question was closed in the first place. If you don't give specific implementation details, all people can do is guess at what you want.

Comment: @XardasLord: So actually it's a `List(Of List(Of Object))`. Instead of `Object` you should use `dr2.GetInt32("Id_produkty")` instead of `dr2("Id_produkty")` to get a `List(Of List(Of Int32))`.

Comment: @XardasLord: i've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time, that you try to help me. I get an error in this line: `produkty.Add(PobierzProduktyKategorii(nazwaSklepu, dr("Id_sklep_kategorie")))`. Error says: `Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer))' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)'`. This is inside `If dr.HasRows` statement